# install pyflann for python 2.7

Tags: python, flann

I would like to use the pyflann module for nearest neighbor search show like here: http://pythonhosted.org/laspy/tut_part_1.html . I have a python 2.7 for ArcGis. Unfortunately the installing guide is not clear for me and I have problem compiling the package (the Laspy is installed with pip without problem). http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/ The guide here says the installation is the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" 
cd flann-x.y.z-src 
mkdir build 
cd build 
cmake .. 
nmake
```

I could find the `vcvarsall. bat` here: `C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0` When I tried to run the `cmake ..` I got an error starting with the C compiler identification is unknown. Here is the errorlog:

```
    Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.23107.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 9/21/2015 7:56:14 PM.


Project "C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
```

> Creating directory "Debug\".

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]



Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\".
```

> InitializeBuildStatus:

```
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
```

> ClCompile:

```
C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/Zc:inline' [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
```

CMakeCCompilerId.c
Link:

```
C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdC.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdC.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdC.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH Debug\CMakeCCompilerId.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'manifest:embed' [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

Build FAILED.

```
"C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(PrepareForBuild target) -> 



C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

"C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) -> 
  cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/Zc:inline' [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]


"C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Link target) -> 
  LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'manifest:embed' [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]

2 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.02

Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: C:\MinGW\bin 
Build flags: 
Id flags:

The output was:
1
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.23107.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
Build started 9/21/2015 7:56:16 PM.
Project "C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
```

C

```
reating directory "Debug\".
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
```

Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:

```
C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/Zc:inline' [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
```

CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Link:

```
`C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdCXX.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdCXX.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH` Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
```

LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'manifest:embed'

```
[C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

Build FAILED.

"

```
C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(PrepareForBuild target) -> 



C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]


"C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) -> 
  cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/Zc:inline' [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]


"C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Link target) -> 
  LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'manifest:embed' [C:\flann-1.8.4-src\build\CMakeFiles\3.3.2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
2 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.65

Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":

Comment: please, do some formatting

Comment: Thanks for the editing, I'm newbie

Comment: `error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". ` so where is your `cl.exe`?

Comment: I have no idea what is the cl.exe